# I am having problem in "fetching" only one entry from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want only one single data from that DB but I am not able to "take it out of" `$res`.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `study_stuffs_extra`.`tid` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1 ";  
$res = query($sql);
$tid = $res['tid'];
```

I have also tried a `while` loop to do so, but "couldn't do it". Is there any other method to "do it"?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `study_stuffs_extra`.`tid` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1 ";  
$res = mysql_query($sql);
$res=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$tid = $res['tid'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT tid FROM study_stuffs_extra ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Also, check what `query` returns. Is that a mysql result? the whole result set? a row? Do some `print_r` to see what you get. Check for db errors after executing queries.

Comment: sql is working good i had test it with phpmyadmin but i an not able to take $res variable out

Comment: I'm not sure how is this related to my advices

Comment: I wish SO would forward all PHP OPs to a basic problem solving page. How to enable displaying php warnings and errors, how to do some *very basic* tracing and check for query errors.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to subscript the first member of `$res`, assuming it is an array.

```
$firstRow = $res[0];
```